# How to chain together Mutations in apollo client

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have a bunch of information stored in my state that I need to pass to my graphQL server using mutations, but I need to use the results of each mutation before I call the next one since I need to:

- Create a new object in my database
- Use the id generated for that object to create another object
- Modify the original object to store the id generated by the second object

I noticed that apollo Mutation components have an onCompleted callback, but I don't know how to use this callback to fire off another mutation or whether it's the right way solve my problem. I also looked into batching my mutations to send them all at once but it doesn't seem like that is the solution either. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you have any control over the server? Is it possible for you to change the API?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you've mentioned, the unique way to solve it is batching all the mutations, check out the [issue related](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/1867)!

Actually, it's not that bad to compose them, you could do something like this:

```
const handleClick = async (mutation1Fn, mutation2Fn, mutation3Fn) => {
  const data1 = await mutation1Fn()
  const data2 = await mutation2Fn()
  const data3 = await mutation3Fn()
}

const Mutations = () => (
  <Composer
    components={[
      <Mutation mutation={mutation1} />,
      <Mutation mutation={mutation2} />,
      <Mutation mutation={mutation3} />
    ]}
  >
    {([mutation1Fn, mutation2Fn, mutation3Fn]) => (
      <button
        onClick={() => handleClick(mutation1Fn, mutation2Fn, mutation3Fn)}
      >
        exec!
      </button>
    )}
  </Composer>
)
```

Let me know if you're struggling with something!

Comment: @CarlosRufo , doesn't the Mutation component need a children prop? How would one handle this?

Comment: @CarlosRudo , also, how can I access the errors, loading, etc. props that the Mutation component passes to its render function

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is nest these mutations depending on the data being passed.

The `onCompleted` and `onError` props can be used in your case, and they have access to the new data result too. But I personally think a nested format is more readable and easier to debug later.

It would be something like:

```jsx
const Mutations = () => (
  <Mutation mutation={m1}>
    {(mutation1, { loading, error, data }) => (
       if (loading) return `Loading...`
       if (error) return `Error...`

       const id = get(data, 'result.id')

       return (
          <Mutation mutation={m2} variables={id} />
            {(mutation2, { loading, error, data }) => (

             if (loading) return `Loading...`
             if (error) return `Error...`

             (...)
            )}
          </Mutation>
     )}
  </Mutation>
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I think I prefer Carlos's answer in terms of formatting and readability.